# running a java program in a unix terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I have a java program with multiple class files and they are all stored in the same folder called lab7. I coded the project in NetBeans so used "package lab7" in all the files. My main application java file is called lab7.java. Now, when i try to run this on the terminal i get "Exception in main thread: NoClassDefFoundError". I do the following inside the folder lab7.

```
   javac *.java
   java  lab7
```

I don't know why get this error. It should be some basic class path error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's more info. on using Java from the command line: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Comment: If you have not set classpaths and whatnot you can do `java -classpath . lab7` after you have `javac`'d it, assuming you are in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

Normally class names should start with a capital letter. So you should rename your main class to `Main`. If it's inside the `lab7` package, run this:

```
java lab7.Main
```

This should be run in the directory that contains the `lab7` directory. So if you're in the `lab7` directory itself, go up one level first.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
java lab7.lab7
```

You do have a lab7.java file with a public static void main(String[]) method, right?